# Why do two English personal pronouns — "you" and "it" — lack an objective case?

Tags: english, cases, pronouns

Most English person pronouns have an objective case — I/me, we/us, thou/thee, he/him, she/her, they/them, who/whom. But "you" and "it" have no such form. Did they every have one? is there any reason for this?

Comment: *you* was [the object pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English#Pronouns). It swallowed up the subject, as well as the singular forms. I'm not sure about *it*. But further questions about older English pronouns should be asked at [english.se].

Comment: Discussion of a similar case on meta: https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2013/17305

Comment: As @curiousdannii says, since we’re including older pronouns, it’s actually _ye/you_, with _you_ being the object form. But _it_ is neuter, and you’ll have to look fairly hard to find neuter words of any kind (pronoun, noun or adjective) that have different nominative/subject and accusative/object forms in _any_ Indo-European language. Identical nominative and accusative forms is in fact one of the things that characterises neuter words all the way back to reconstructed Proto-Indo-European.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Not too hard, the Slavic languages do have that distinction: Russian _животное_ (životnoe) ‘animal’ is neuter, Acc. is _животного_ (životnogo) = Gen., a usual thing with animate nouns. But also ‘it’: Nom. _оно/ono_, Acc. is Russ. _его_ (jego), Pol. _je_, Cro.-Serb. _njega, ga_, Cz. _ho, je_. Note that in OCS there was no such distinction, Nom.=Acc. was for all the neuter and masculine singular nouns (except for stems ending in a consonant) and for the 3 p. personal and demonstrative pronouns, that distinction in the modern Slavic languages is surely an innovation.

Comment: @YellowSky. That is a valid point. In Russian the classic system of gender is partially reinterpreted as an animate/inanimate contrast. If I am not mistaken, this happened quite recently in the history of Russian.

Comment: @fdb - It all depends on the meaning of ”quite recently”, besides, it's an all-Slavic phenomenon, not just Russian. The process started already in OCS with the rise of the person/non-person distinction in nouns, when Gen. forms were used as Acc. for nouns denoting socially competent males and male proper names. Later, it took its own specific forms in each modern Slavic language, e.g. in Polish it is still connected with gender and person/non-person, all the feminine animate plural nouns having Acc. pl. = Nom. pl. the same way as the inanimate pl. and animate non-person male pl.  nouns.

Comment: @fdb Unfortunately, Yellow Sky has given **misleading** information. Animate neuter nouns in Present-Day Standard Russian (as spoken by educated Russians living in Russia) have different forms in the nom. and acc. plural only; in the singular the nom. and acc. sg. these forms are identical. That is why acc. sg. is "вижу/изучаю/люблю животное" but in the plural it is "вижу/изучаю/люблю животных". I even checked the "bible on the Russian declension paradigms" (i.e. Zalizniak) and he says the same thing. The acc. sg. "животного" (насекомого etc.) sounds plainly wrong.

Comment: @AlexB. - Yes... You're right... My bad, I was thinking about the plural, but somehow wrote the singular. Nevertheless, the part about ‘it’ is correct, and that's the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for undeleting it. I disagree. Your case would be stronger if you could be specific what in the site guidelines suggests that this is not on topic. The question, "is there any reason for this?" does require linguistic expertise. The realization that we often get nom=acc is only the beginning. Is this only in IE or a wider phenomenon? If the latter, could there be a cognitive linguistic explanation for it?

Comment: @Yellow Sky No worries. I never thought about it myself before, so now we both know.

Comment: @Keelan Sure, interesting linguistic questions could be asked about early Modern English, but for someone with so little familiarity about the language ELU is probably going to be the more helpful site. Your interesting question ideas are ones that would need a linguist to answer, but questions like this, about the basic existence of pronouns, do not.

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't see where you're getting from that this is someone with "little familiarity about the language". All I was doing is unpacking the question "is there any reason for this?" for you. Clearly it is of linguistic relevance. You seem to limit yourself to "Did they every have one?", but if you read the body in full this cannot be called a question about "the basic existence of pronouns".

Comment: @AlexB. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Very illuminating. As I understand it:
1. it - neuter singular pronoun is a specific instance of a neuter singular word, and for those words it is common that nominative and accusative have the same form. That takes care of that.
2. you - Juas as thou/thee fell from usage, replaced by ye/you (both singular and plural, but keeping the plural form of the verb), so also "ye" fell from usage, leaving "you" to take on nominative as well as accusative duty for one or multiple persons being addressed. 

That's what I understand from the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*it* is not too surprising, but the collapse of *thou*/*thee* and *ye*/*you* into *you* is notable and rare among the languages of the wider Western world at least.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou#General_decline_in_Early_Modern_English

> Fairly suddenly in the 17th century, *thou* began to decline in the standard language (that is, particularly in and around London), often regarded as impolite or ambiguous in terms of politeness. It persisted, sometimes in an altered form, particularly in regional dialects of England and Scotland farther from London, as well as in the language of such religious groups as the Society of Friends. **Reasons commonly maintained by modern linguists as to the decline of thou in the 17th century include the increasing identification of you with "polite society" and the uncertainty of using thou for inferiors versus you for superiors (with you being the safer default) amidst the rise of a new middle class.**

See also: [Middle English creole hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_creole_hypothesis).

Comment: 2sg pronouns losing out to other forms isn’t all _that_ unusual. For instance, in most of South America (both Spanish and Portuguese), the _tu/tú_ forms are rarely used, forms based on the third person (_usted/você_) or 2pl (_vos_) having more or less ousted them.

Comment: Yes but they still distinguish between nominative forms and accusative, dative etc., e.g. for *usted* and *ustedes* it's *lo* or *la*, *le*, *los* or *las* and *les*.

Comment: True, the combination of 2sg -> 2pl _and_ nom -> acc is very unusual. In fact, just the complete conflation of nom/acc in just one personal pronoun (with no conflation in any of the others) is highly unusual. I can’t think of a single parallel for that.

Comment: By the way, I agree there are parallels to the rise of *Usted* and *você*, but the question was asking more about the accusative and dative.

Comment: Yeah, I got distracted by the talk about the singular/plural conflation and forgot what the main question was. Modern Gaelic languages have also levelled case in pronouns, but that’s throughout the paradigm, not just in one particular pronoun (well, it’s only in about half of them in Irish, but the development of a nom/acc distinction in _tú/thú_, _sé/é_, _sí/í_ and _siad/iad_ is a more recent thing there).

Answer (score 8):

I would not say that these pronouns lack an objective case. It is just that the subject (nominative) and object (accusative) forms are identical. In Old English, as in virtually all Indo-European languages, neuter nouns and pronouns always have the same form in the nominative and accusative, in the case of Old English "hit" for the 3rd person singular neuter. This is striking archaic feature in modern English.

Comment: Yet somebody else in the comments is saying that *ye* was the subject and *you* comes from the object form. Can you comment on that?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that whatever reasons there are are historical. If you look at related Germanic languages, they all have the same form for the neuter singular pronoun in the nominative and accusative (Dutch het, German es, Norwegian det, Icelandic það, for example), but all them of them that I can think of distinguish the two cases in the second person singular (Dutch jij/jou, German du/dich, Norwegian du/deg, Icelandic þú/þig). When one form is used for two functions, as in the neuter singular it is called syncretism; the nom/acc syncretism for neuter singular is an old Indo-European trait. Apart from the neuter singular, there is some variation even within the Germanic languages whether a language distinguishes nominative and accusative or whether a single form is syncretic for both. Icelandic distinguishes nom and acc in second person plural (þið vs. ykkur) and third person masculine plural (þeir vs. þá), but has nom/acc syncretism in the masculine singular (hann) and in the feminine plural (þær). German has nom/acc syncretism in the feminine singular (sie) and the third person plural (also sie), but distinguishes them in the masculine singular (er vs. ihn).